# Conventional flux in centrifuge?

Tags: diffusion

The molecules sediment in centrifuge, which is rotating with angular velocity $\omega$. The chemical potential of molecule (considering potential associated with centrifuge force) is:

$$\mu_i=\mu_i^0+RT\ln a_i -M_i\omega^2r^2/2$$

$$\dfrac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial r}=0+\dfrac{RT\partial a_i}{a_i \partial r}-M_i\omega^2r$$

The total diffusion flux is:

$$J_i=\dfrac{1}{6}C\beta^2 \nu \exp \left(-\dfrac{\Delta_{diff}G}{RT}\right)\dfrac{a_ia_j}{RT \gamma}\left(\dfrac{\partial \mu_j}{\partial r}-\dfrac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial r}\right),$$

where $i$ - stands for molecules and $j$ - solvent. If we assume that concentration of molecules  are low ($c\rightarrow 0$, $\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial r}=0$) one can get:

$$J_i=\dfrac{1}{6}C\beta^2 \nu \exp\left(-\dfrac{\Delta_{diff}G}{RT}\right)\left(-\dfrac{\partial a_i}{\gamma \partial r}+\dfrac{a_iM_i\omega^2r}{\gamma RT}\right)$$

My problem is this: I know that conventional flux should be equaled to:
$$J_i^{conv}=vc_i,$$

where $c_i$-concentration of molecules.

I do not understand how to reduce my equation and extract convectional part and so called  *ordinary* part ($J\sim \dfrac{\partial c_i}{\partial r}) $ of diffusion. Any suggestions?